# Concatenating similar Objects

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list of 9 `ParseObject`'s (just like normal `Object`) on my list that have properties `name`,`capacity` and `price`:

```
Aaa | 2 | 6
Aaa | 3 | 8
Aaa | 4 | 9
Bbb | 2 | 5
Bbb | 3 | 7
Bbb | 4 | 9
Ccc | 2 | 3
Ccc | 3 | 4
Ccc | 4 | 8
```

What I want to achieve is list of 3 `ParseObject`'s items like this:

```
Aaa: 2/6 | 3/8 | 4/9;
Bbb: 2/5 | 3/7 | 4/9;
Ccc: 2/3 | 3/4 | 4/8;
```

I thought about using comparator while sorting but no idea how to get it done. I want to show all prices for same object in one place instead of having them seperated.

Comment: But that implies you need to modify your object model or at least create a new one right?

Comment: @Nanoc That's right, I thought about the same. Additionaly, some of the objects have just one price. Whatever what will do the job.

Comment: @Nanoc or it can be even the same object model - I just need that to show so for example: I can concat all `capacity` and `name` params in two `String`s like `String s1 = price + "/" + price2 + "/" + price3;` and the same with capacity

Comment: You could make a for loop to do that but i cant understand whats your problem with that. what are you missing to do it?

Comment: I'm looking for most efficent and code effective way to do that. Maybe there are functions I don't know that can help with that.

Comment: Okay, I found first problem: I can't concat `Number` fields which of type are `cena` and `pojemnosc`